# Office.js collaborate on a document

Tags: javascript, office-js

I have the following use case:

- user creates a document and stores it to OneDrive
- user invites another user to work on the same document at the same time

Since this is supported by Word, there are no issues. However, I wan't the users to both be able to use an add-in I'm working on. The add in injects some ContentControl objects into the document and while both users can do it, it does not behave properly.

If I got it right, for the collaboration to work, the add-in should use the `Office.context.document.settings.refreshAsync(callback);` method. This method has proven to be very slow in my case (sometimes up to 10 seconds, depending on the amount of ContentControl objects I have inserted in the document through the add-in). That is why I'd like to avoid using the method above whenever there is no collaboration.

My question is - is there any way to know, inside Office.js, that a collaboration exists? That way I could easily switch between `refreshAsync()` and just accessing the `settings` object when there is no collaboration happening at that moment.

Comment: From what I can tell this is not possible. The current documentation does not mention any method in order to figure out whether anyone has opened or is editing the document.

Comment: @Fluous thanks, that's what I thought, but it was worth a shot.